# Verificar o objeto do arrayList em tempo de execução

Tags: java, arraylist

Tenho um arraylist com três posições. Adicionei ao array, objetos do tipo Gerente, Vendedor e Tecnico, respectivamente. Utilizando o `getClass`, gostaria de saber como faço para saber qual objeto esta em cada posição do vetor.

Fiz desta forma mas, não gerou nenhum erro e nem chamou os meus métodos.

```
public static void mostrarSalarioFuncionario() {

        ArrayList<Funcionario> listaFunc = new ArrayList<Funcionario>();
        listaFunc.add(ge);
        listaFunc.add(te);
        listaFunc.add(ve);
        System.out.println("CALCULO SALARIO DO FUNCIONARIO");
        for (int i = 0; i < listaFunc.size(); i++) {


            if (listaFunc.get(i).getClass().equals(ge) {
                System.out.println("Classe...:Gerente");
                System.out.println("Salário..:"+ge.calcularSalario());;
            }

            else if(listaFunc.get(i).getClass().equals(ve)) {
                System.out.println("Classe...:Vendedor");
                System.out.println("Salário..:"+ve.calcularSalario());;
            }

            else if (listaFunc.get(i).getClass().equals(te)) {
                System.out.println("Classe...:Técnico");
                System.out.println("Salário..:"+te.calcularSalario());
            }
}
```

Comment: Use `instance of` ao inves de `getClass`. Eu até mostraria um exemplo, mas esse trecho de código não faz sentido com a duvida da pergunta.

Comment: reformulei a questão poderia exemplificar com instance of?

Comment: O que é te e ve?

Comment: um objeto do tipo Vendedor e do tipo Tecnico

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilize `instanceof` para verificar o subtipo do objeto:

```
for (int i = 0; i < listaFunc.size(); i++) {

    System.out.println("Classe:"+listaFunc.get(i).getClass().getName().substring(32));
    if (listaFunc.get(i) instanceof Gerente) {
        System.out.println("Classe...:Gerente");
        System.out.println("Salário..:"+ge.calcularSalario());;
    }

    else if(listaFunc.get(i) instanceof Vendedor) {
        System.out.println("Classe...:Vendedor");
        System.out.println("Salário..:"+ve.calcularSalario());;
    }

    else if (listaFunc.get(i) instanceof Tecnico) {
        System.out.println("Classe...:Técnico");
        System.out.println("Salário..:"+te.calcularSalario());
    }
}
```

Comment: realmente assim foi muito mais fácil, a minha dúvida era se com instance of precisaria do .get(i). Obrigado novamente diegofm

Comment: @DiogoLopes o instanceof verifica se um objeto a esquerda é do tipo da classe a direita, então precisaria do get(i), já que esse método retorna o objeto instanciado que está na lista.